# PS1 on .zshrc outputs string instead of desired outputs

Tags: macos, terminal, macos-catalina, zshrc, ps1

I'm using Mac OS Catalina.

I tried editting .zshrc file with
`export PS1="\u \w \$ "`
and my expected output would be `user desktop $`.
However the actual output was `\u \w $`. I don't understand why `\u` or `\w` is not working.

.zshrc file is located in /Users/(username) and I editted the file with VS code.
I checked that `SHELL=/bin/zsh`.

I literally have no idea why this is not working. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Include that's line in file ~.zshrc :

```
export PS1="%10F%n%f:%11F%1~%f \$ "
```

for other options see this site : http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html

Answer (score 0):

Literally I spent hours before posting this question, but right after I posted, I found a solution.

zsh seems to use different expansion, darn!
http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html